# How to type-annotate a file-like object in Python 3.8+

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing

Previously [`typing.IO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.IO), `typing.TextIO`, and `typing.BinaryIO` were available to annotate file-like objects, e.g. those returned by `open()`. However, after Python 3.8 they seem to be deprecated, and will be removed in Python 3.12. Unlike many of the other deprecations like `typing.List[T]`, which is replaced by `list[T]`, these IO types have no clear migration path.

How should file-like object types be annotated in modern Python, going forward?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python 3.9 [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/typing.html#typing.IO) has an unclear notice:

> *"These types are also in the `typing.io` namespace, which was never supported by type checkers and will be removed."*

See more in the discussion ["[docs] Confusing deprecation notice for typing.IO"](https://bugs.python.org/issue44925)

In the [new version](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/typing.html#typing.IO) of the docs it's fixed:

> *"The `typing.io` namespace is deprecated and will be removed. These types should be directly imported from typing instead."*

Comment: Oh I see, so these types themselves aren't actually deprecated. We're just supposed to replace `typing.io.IO` with `typing.IO` etc going forward.